# Computing the general symmetry group of cubic polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, polynomials

I'm attempting to compute the group of continuous (or more generally holomorphic) $\phi: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\phi(x)) = f(x)$.

In the linear setting, $f = ax + b$ we don't see anything interesting, the group $\phi$ is trivial.

In the quadratic setting, we note that $f = x^2$ has symmetry group $\lbrace x, -x \rbrace$, has $x^2 = (-x)^2$ and to go a step further, we can complete the square on any $ax^2 + bx + c$, to derive:

$$ ax^2 + bx + c =  a \left(x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x + \frac{c}{a}\right) = a\left( x + \frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 + c  - \frac{b^2}{4a} $$

And thus generally it has symmetry group $\lbrace x, -x-\frac{b}{2a} \rbrace$,

Now the cubic case becomes much trickier. we can extrapolate from $f = x^3$ to the general $e_0(x+e_1)^3 + e_2$ but this doesn't cover all possible cubic polynomials.

Any idea how to dig deeper here and compute the symmetries of all cubic polynomials?